# Sum of determinants of constrained matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $S$ is the set containing matrices of order $3$ and the entries of the matrices are from the set $\{1,3,5,7,11\}$.
Then find the average of the determinants of matrices in $S$.

I know the numbers of such matrices is $5^3$, but I cannot find the sum of determinants of such matrices.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Hint: If $B$ is obtained from $A$ by interchanging two rows, then what is $\det(B)$ (in terms of $\det(A)$)?

Comment: Det B=(-1)^3 Det(A)

Comment: Then what is to do.pls tell me.how I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the map: $$\varphi:\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\ a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\ a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{pmatrix}\to
\begin{pmatrix}a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\\ a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\ a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $\det\varphi(A)=-\det A$ and as $\varphi$ is 1-1-map we have 
$$\sum \det A = \sum \det\varphi(A)=  -\sum \det A $$ 
so $\sum \det A =0.$